# Specifying endpoint without configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, owin, azure-service-fabric

In our stateless service, we've got:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new OwinCommunicationListener(Startup.ConfigureApp,
                serviceContext, ServiceEventSource.Current, "ServiceEndpoint"))
        };
    }
```

.

**"ServiceEndpoint"** refers to settings in the ServiceManifest.xml file:

```
  <Resources>
<Endpoints>
  <!-- This endpoint is used by the communication listener to obtain the port on which to 
       listen. Please note that if your service is partitioned, this port is shared with 
       replicas of different partitions that are placed in your code. -->
  <Endpoint Protocol="https" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" />
</Endpoints>
```

**Is it possible to simply pass "https" as a string, rather than have OwinCommunicationListener have to get it from configuration?**

The result would be something like this:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new OwinCommunicationListener(Startup.ConfigureApp,
                serviceContext, ServiceEventSource.Current, "https"))
        };
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the same but have a look at this code and see if you can get any ideas from it https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-management-party-cluster/blob/master/src/PartyCluster.WebService/OwinCommunicationListener.cs

Comment: Found another example https://gist.github.com/enemaerke/014e20eaaeb2a29a06b3